Merge multiple text files in linux bash with each line to go under the line of other file
Merge multiple files, with each line under the line of other file.
Example:
fileA
1
4
7

fileB
2
5
8

fileC
3
6
9

result:
file_output
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9


You can use the paste command, which normally combines the lines of all files into a longer line, and specify a newline as the separator.
paste -d $'\n' fileA fileB fileC > file_output

writes the expected output as specified in the question to the output file.
You can also use
paste -d '\n' fileA fileB fileC > file_output

The difference is that $'\n' gets replaces with a newline by the shell while '\n' (without $) gets interpreted by paste.

For your information: The usual output of
paste fileA fileB fileC

with TAB as the default separator would be
1       2       3
4       5       6
7       8       9


this is not the desired output, but paste -d'\n' fileA fileB fileC produces the desired output. Please edit your answer to accept it.

@Estatistics Please be more specific. What is not the desired output? The output from paste -d $'\n' fileA fileB fileC > file_output?

i didnt say anywhere  an output of the "lines side by side".... each single number is a line itself. i pasted the desired output that 3 appears below 2 and 2 appears below 1. Maybe the view of your browser/computer showed them side by side?

@Estatistics My answer shows a command to get the expected output from the first version. I added the side-by-side output only as additional information because this is the main use case of the paste command.

Noted:
$ cat fileA fileB fileC | sort > file_output # will produce the expected result.
also:
 $ sort --help
...
-n, --numeric-sort          compare according to string numerical value


could be random numbers in random queue, random letters, random strings. These numbers where given only for example.

@Estatistics you should update the example to make it less confusing

With GNU pr and bash
pr -m -t -J -s$'\n' file{A,B,C}



Just redirect the output to a file

